# Should we approve minor suggested edits, but with no rep gain for the editor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

After browsing the site for a while, the only reason I have seen to reject correct but too minor suggested edits is to discourage the not-very-helpful editors. The edits are still helpful, but not helpful enough, so they are rejected to not encourage the editor with a reputation reward. This doesn't make sense to me; any suggested edits that are the slightest bit helpful should still be approved.

Why don't we just **approve minor edits, but not give the editor reputation**? That way, most helpful suggested edits get approved, but users aren't encouraged to continue making minor suggested edits.

---

An *example* of a way I can see this happening is when someone click approve, this happens:

> [image]

- Yes: +1 minor vote
- No: -1 minor vote
- Maybe: +0 minor votes

```
if minor_votes > 1:          rep_gain = 0
else if minor_votes < -1:    rep_gain = 2
else:                        rep_gain = 1
```

But that's just a possibility.

Comment: Not sure I like the idea, but at the very least don't withhold rep because it's "minor", but because it's "too minor". If you're going to ask if the edit was "minor" all you get is "yeah, that's not a lot of characters". When the edit was complete, that's just wrong.

Comment: I'm in favor, particularly when the edit is correct and improves the post, but there's still work that needs to be done, and the editor should have handled more fixes at the same time. I usually end up voting to reject as too minor, but the edit nonetheless would have helped.

Comment: I actually spend more time worrying about whether an edit should be considered "too minor" or not than whether it's correct etc. If the decision was less important I'd spend less time on it.

Comment: Should this information also feed the decision to bump the question on the front page?

Comment: I mostly reject "too minor" edits because of the undeserved bumping to the front page, and also the unwarranted distortion of the integrity of the original authorship.  That said, I start to wonder if risking losing a point or two of rep when a suggestion is rejected might start to be an appropriate deterrent to pointless editing.

Comment: This is a better idea now that edits don't push the question into Community Wiki.

Comment: This can be dome semi-automatically with the existing system. When the edit is (robo-)approved but at least one reviewer actually looked into the edits and rejected as "too minor", the system could use that information without presenting (robo-)approvers with additional dialogs.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin But then a single person has the ability to prevent someone from getting reputation, no matter how good the edit is.

Comment: Just use at least two "too minor" rejects as in your proposal. This is immaterial, the actual weights can be anything. The main thing is that the system already has that kind of data.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin But what if three people reject as too minor? Then the edit doesn't get approved, even if it did improve the post some small amount.

Comment: I believe that right now if three people reject the edit for whatever reason the edit gets rejected. Quite obviously, too.

Comment: @chrylis - I agree with you, I have seen many approved edits that are extremely minor, for example only removing the "thank you" at the bottom of the post while the rest of it is a mess.  But I wonder what is the line for considering something as "too minor". I have done really few characters edits in cases where there was something wrong with the code that made it not work properly, at first sight is really minor, but I believe valuable, specially if you are a newbie and find an up-voted question that doesn't have working code. It can he confusing.

Comment: @Dzyann "Too minor" means "helpful but doesn't fix the majority of the problems, unless it fixes a huge issue in the post" or something like that.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - I think some people don't correct everything, because they read it as being ok, for example non-native English Speaker could see some things wrong and fix them, but ignore the rest, because for him looks ok. In a situation like that, where the user has probably done everything he thought was required, but the post still required a lot of work, what would be the desired output? And what do you think would actually happen?

Answer (score 10):

I like this concept, but not the implementation.  At the moment, you're adding two additional clicks, one on a radio button, and one on the Approve button inside the popup.  On opposite sides of the screen, even.

How about just splitting the existing Approve button into "Approve" and "Approve and Rep"?

That has the added benefit that reviewers who aren't paying attention (aka *robo-reviewers*) are likely to hit the 'No Rep' version, since it has the button name they're accustomed to thoughtlessly clicking.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would cause people not to get reputation because someone robo-reviewed even if the edit was good?

Comment: @Dzyann: Correct, and I consider that an acceptable price to pay in exchange for not giving rep to bad edits which are robo-approved.  Remember that this won't change the maximum amount of reputation good editors get from edits, it will just take somewhat longer to reach the maximum -- and still is quite fast.

Comment: But don't you think that could trigger a lot of users asking here why didn't they get reputation?

Comment: @Dzyann: Nope. At least, less likely than the ones already asking why they didn't get reputation (A: edit was rejected) or the other ones asking why they didn't get reputation (A: edit is still in review queue).  Not to mention the ones complaining that they didn't get reputation (A: reviewer used "Reject and Improve" button).  The only way a user learns that their edit has been accepted and they haven't gotten reputation is by looking at a screen that can also explain why.